# How to Customize Popup for Add New in ASP.NET MVC Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I click Add New button from Grid then I want to customize the popup. How can I do this?
[image]

I also want to rename fields title (i.e., Name to something else, Photo64 to Photo ...). How can I do this?

Comment: Could you provide some code e.g. grid initialization and grid model class?

Answer (score 1):

You can change title of window by javascript. The example is here [how to Change Caption of popup kendo grid by html helper in add window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284566/how-to-change-caption-of-popup-kendo-grid-by-html-helper-in-add-window)

Telerik kendo grid uses for creating item editor from asp.net mvc. Create editor for User in this folder Views/Shared/EditorTemplates to modify default view.

Comment: I cannot find anything named EditorTemplates in Views/Shared folder.

Comment: Create sub-folder EditorTemplates manually, then add User.cshtml to this folder.